# Why can't I retrieve image in Google App Engine?

Tags: json, google-app-engine, jsp

I'm learning how to code in Java and Google App Engine.  I want to retrieve some images that I uploaded to the Google App database and display them. My code compiles, but the images aren't displayed in the browser.  All I see is a small square.

I am suspecting the bug is in the viewimage.jsp file before.  Can someone take a look at some of my jsp files and give me some suggestions? Your help is greatly appreciated. Thank u!

viewimage.jsp

```
<%@ page import="javax.jdo.*" %>
<%@ page import="com.*" %>
<%
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.getPMF().getPersistenceManager();
    try {
        String itemId = request.getParameter("item");

        Item item = (Item)pm.getObjectById(Item.class, Long.parseLong(itemId));
        byte[] photo = item.getPhoto(item);
        response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
        response.getOutputStream().write(photo);
    } catch (Exception cannotLoad) {
        cannotLoad.printStackTrace(); 
    } finally {
        pm.close();
    }
%>
```

view.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
    <title>CS496 Homework 2 - Display Page</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var MOBILE = navigator.userAgent.match(
                    /Android|BlackBerry|iPhone|iPad|iPod|IEMobile/i) ? true : false;
    if (MOBILE) { 
        document.write("<link rel=stylesheet href='http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css'>");
        document.write("<link rel=stylesheet href='stylemobile.css'>");
        document.write('<s'+'cript src="jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></scr'+'ipt>');
    } else
        document.write("<link rel=stylesheet href='styledesktop.css'>");
    </script>

</head><body>

<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>CS496 Homework 2</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content" class="photolist"> 
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="allitems"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="detailPage">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1 id="detailTitle"></h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content" id="detailContent" class="photoViewer">    
        <img src="" id="detailImage">
    </div>
</div>

<script>
function addItemMobile(itemId, school) {
    var anchor = $("<a/>").text(school).attr('href', '#detailPage').click(function() { 
        $("#detailTitle").text(school);
        $("#detailImage").attr('src', '');
        $("#detailImage").attr('src', 'viewimage.jsp?item='+itemId);
    });
    var li = $("<li/>").append(anchor);
    $("#allitems").append(li);
}

function addItemDesktop(itemId, school) {
    var loc = $("#allitems");
    loc.append($("<h2 />").text(school));
    loc.append($("<div />").append($("<img />").attr('src', 'viewimage.jsp?item='+itemId)));
}

var addItem = MOBILE ? addItemMobile : addItemDesktop;

$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    dataType:"json",
    url:"viewapi.jsp",
    success:function(items) {
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            var item = items[i];
            addItem(item.id, item.school);
        }
        $("#allitems").listview('refresh');
    },
    error:function(a,b,c) {
        alert("ERROR: "+a);
    }
});

</script>


</body></html>
```

viewapi.jsp

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="javax.jdo.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.json.simple.*" %>
<%@ page import="cs496hwk2.*" %>
<%
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.getPMF().getPersistenceManager();
    try {
        List<Item> items = Item.loadItems(null, pm);
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
        for (Item item : items) {
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
            object.put("id", item.getID());
            object.put("school", item.getSchool());
            array.add(object);
        }
        out.write(array.toString());
    } finally {
        pm.close();
    }
%>
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging with the Chrome debugger or Firebug/Firefox? You can check the src URL of the image is as intended, and you can view the HTTP requests and responses to look for clues.

Comment: Try to remove the stuff that are not relevant at all you to your problem.. it's going to be easier for you and for all of use to locate the problem.. just pasting the whole thing is not a very good practice.. and you'll have more chances to actually solving the problem..

Comment: Code tldr but for starters yiu should not store images in the datastore for many reasons (like max size). Use blobstore.

Comment: @ZigMandel: This is for a homework assignment. It is a requirement to store images in the datastore.

Comment: I tried Chrome debugger and saw the error messages: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method "list view". Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Unable to compile class for JSP:   An error occurred at line: 9 in the jsp file: /viewimage.jsp The method getPhoto() in the type Item is not applicable for the arguments (Item) 6.....

Comment: Please post the code of your `Item` class, you're using its `getPhoto()` method incorrectly.

Comment: I'd also suggest using a Servlet instead of a JSP to serve binary data like images -- JSPs are much more suitable for web pages of HTML (hence their name). Your JSP accidentally inserts a line break after the first two `%>`s.